What will be the format of the FIFA Club World Cup after the 2025 edition?
Traditionally, the FIFA Club World Cup involved 7 teams. The first, in 2000, involved 8 teams, while the 2005 and 2006 editions involved only 6. Now the 2025 edition will involve 32 teams, similar to the national teams' World Cup.
What will happen after that? Will they return to the traditional format, will they be playing a 32-team format each 4 years and the 7-team format each year, will they be playing the 32-team format each year, or what?
What will be the format of the FIFA Club World Cup after the 2025 edition?


will they be playing a 32-team format each 4 years and the 7-team format each year

This is actually quite close to what FIFA are doing. The Club World Cup is being moved to a quadrennial format, with the 32-team format being permanent for the foreseeable future. However, a new annual 6-team tournament, the FIFA Intercontinental Cup, has been created that will essentially take the place of the old Club World Cup, with each year's champions from all six continents competing in a straight knockout tournament.

So in 2025 we will have 2 "FIFA club world cup" tournaments, one with 32 teams and one with 6 teams?

Essentially, yes.

This is quite a mess. When FIFA created the original FIFA club world cup, they made official the intercontinental cup as a "world champions" cup, so now we have several incoherent options 1) - Either The champions of the new "intercontinental cup" which has the same format of the old club world cup, won't be world champions, but teams which played a much smaller tournament (the original intercontinental cup) will be, or in 2025 (and 2029, 2033, etc) we will have 2 world champions in the same year

I agree, but frankly FIFA's entire decision-making process for this was "more matches = more money".
